# Self Organizing Map training strategy in Encog

Tags: neural-network, encog

I am trying to train a SOM using Encog3. There are two examples of doing this in encog-examples - one is training an XOR SOM where all the data is used for training until convergence, and the Color SOM where one out of 15 colors is sampled randomly at each of 1000 iterations. My question is if the second approach was so the example completed with adequate results in a short enough time or if there was a reason for this. If I were to train with all 15 input colors at each iteration, would it have created better results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what results you are looking for.  This is a very common example for SOM's.  Here is a more lengthy description (not written by me) of exactly the same thing.

http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/som/som2.html

The purpose of the example is to show how patterns emerge from the training of an SOM.  Most of the color examples I've seen for SOM do it this way (online training).  It causes the output to be more varied/random.

SOM's can be trained in batch.  It is not a difficult modification to the example.  If you are looking for quick convergence, then yes, you get better results.  However, the example quickly converges to close to a single color, and very quickly.  You do not get the animated convergence to several colors that most of these examples look for.

Comment: My use case was to visualize word vectors created by gensim's word2vec. I ran it through 1000 iterations of online (where it sampled one of my 250 word vectors at each iteration) vs a batch one (where it used all 250 word vectors at each stage). Both outputs reveal interesting patterns but the batch approach takes half a day and the online approach less than couple of minutes.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for your help, and to close the loop, my use case and solution using a combination of gensim and encog3 is more fully described in my blog post: http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2014/10/clustering-word-vectors-using-self.html

Comment: Hey @JeffHeaton I have the data that comes from accelerometer, so 3 axis/ vectors (x[], y[], z[]). I will use this data to recognize movements. I want to use NN with unsupervisied training because I will record movement only once and than compare it with the some saved. Can you tell me what encog implementation should I use, and how to build data when are 3 vector which class to use?